# Good documentation for Gtk-perl

Tags: perl, user-interface

Has anyone found a good place to look for documentation for Gtk-perl?

I thought having a GUI on top of my script would be cool. Oddly enough I seemed to underestimate how much work it takes...

Anyhow I have sort of settled on Gtk-Perl I like they way it flows (more of less).

The problem I am having though is there is no good documentation for it on the developers sourceforge page. So I am left having to Google for an scraps I can find.

I found a decent slideshow that showed the basics and I started to pick it up sorta quick. But then I started to have issues with being unable to figure out how to make certain things work. Like for example my button become MASSIVE when I expand the window. My buttons are tied to a table and I think that has something to do it with it but I can't find out how to really anchor things to the windows. I was thinking VBOX and HBOX objects but once the documentation is difficult to find.

Anyone? Anything? Please.

Comment: Do you create your widgets (ie buttons) programmatically?

Comment: The last time I used gtk, it was through Python and [libglade](http://www.jamesh.id.au/software/libglade/). I enjoyed it enough that I recommend trying `libgtk2-gladexml-perl` or `libgtk2-gladexml-simple-perl` packages, and see if GLADE makes your task easier too.

Comment: Did you look at the GTK documentation? Bindings for other languages often only provide a very thin wrapper around the C libraries.

Comment: Horses for courses - Perl has been bent to do many many things, some of which it is not entirely suited to.  Think about using another language for a nice GUI, then Perl to do your processing.  Every time I've come across a GUI written in Perl it has been clunky, whereas using Perl to actually do some processing is often a very good idea.  Your GUI should be kept separate from your processing with a clearly defined interface between the two so no reason to use Perl everwhere.

Comment: _[Toby Martin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/315182/toby-martin)_: Have a look at **[Padre](http://padre.perlide.org/)** which is written using [wxPerl](http://wxperl.sourceforge.net/). It is an example of a successful GUI project in Perl. It inspired me to write a [wxPerl](http://wxperl.sourceforge.net/) based software for small-scale banks, which has been commercially successful too.

Comment: musiKk has the right of it -- there's no specific documentation for most of the GTK API in Gtk-Perl; you're expected to read the docs for the C API and translate. This is covered specifically in http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Gtk2 and http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Gtk2::api .

Comment: Alan Haggai Alavi - That looks to be an interesting project.  Many thanks for the tip.

Comment: Yeah I have figured that out, some addons to perl are just a sliver of the actual API they are wraping. GTK2+ is crazy powerful but the perl implementation is ...eh...

Comment: @Solignis no, Gtk2 is 100% (well, 99.9%) of the GTK+ 2 API.

Comment: @Hobbs, I was not referring to the GTK API so much as the GTK-Perl API.

Comment: @Solignis and they're the same thing. That's the point.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't any Perl-specific documentation for the majority of the GTK+ API; you're expected to read the [GTK+ 3 Reference Manual](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/) for the C API and translate to Perl. This fact is mentioned in the [Gtk2 perldoc](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Gtk2) and the details of how to translate (naming conventions, mapping C types to Perl objects, how to use callbacks, etc.) are given in [Gtk2::api](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Gtk2::api).  Anything that *isn't* mentioned as an exception should be expected to translate directly.

Comment: Well IMO gtk-perl is sorta hackish to a point. Maybe I should look else where for a GUI solution. I got a friend who is decent at PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Dirk van der Walt's [Gtk2-Perl Study Guide](http://gtk2-perl.sourceforge.net/doc/gtk2-perl-study-guide/) is a great starting point for getting up to speed with the basics.  Unfortunately, for reference material, you really are expected to refer to the docs for the C libraries.  The other thing you should do is get on the [gtk-perl mailing list](http://mail.gnome.org/mailman/listinfo/gtk-perl-list) it's not a high traffic list and the participants are extraordinarily helpful.

Comment: Yeah I found the study guide, it was really good. I am starting to think I should just stop with the perl+GUI before I am in too deep. I would still consider myself a perl novice.

Comment: Hi, i've done dictionary with perl-gtk, www.sympahty.org, you could download .deb package unpackage and see code there, i used Gtk2-Perl Study Guide, but many things weren't there so i've used also C API and digging on Google :), i think if there would be virtual machine (it is preparing in Perl 6 -Parrot) and better compiling and OS independent distributions Perl could be something like Java is now in the world